# Responsive mobile site: huge margins, fonts on mocks

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

got a project mocks where **font-size** values are **25px** to **80px**. And margins are definitely too big. When I test the layout in *Chrome mobile emulator* these fonts look huge.
Is there any reason to use such a huge font values? Or might it be a mistake of design agency?

Answer (score 1):

You may try font size like;

```
font-size:medium;
```

The values can be like;

`xx-small`,`x-small`,`small`,`large`,`xlarge`,`xxlarge`,`smaller`,`larger`,`initial`,`inherit` etc

Also, you may try percentage, like `50%`, `200%` etc.

You may have a look at **[CSS Font-Size: em vs. px vs. pt vs. percent](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)**

Hope this helps.

*Note: Always show us a code to help you. This is how SO works*